# Best way to do error handling in a Discord.JS bot?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

In my Discord.JS bot, I need to be able to handle all uncaught exceptions.

I understand that I can use [`process.on('uncaughtException',. . .'`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-uncaughtexception), but I need the ability to send a message to the channel where the error was triggered (if the error was triggered by a command, of course), and send instructions to report the error (I already have the error reporting method figured out, and I know how to do it without giving them a stack trace or other info - that is not my question).

Of course, I could always just put a `try` statement in every single part of the code where this is the slightest chance of an error, but this would get *very* messy. Of course, I could have a module that does the error handling, but what happens if I need to add another argument to the error handler that will require a change in the try statements? I will have to spend hours going through every single file in the bot.

I understand that I will probably need to have *some* try statements and other error handling methods, but I need to find a more efficient way to do this if possible.

Edit: Yes, I have already tried using a try-catch statement in the command handler. It did nothing. Code:

```js
const {bot} = require('../index');
const { logError } = require("./utils/ErrorHandling.js");

bot.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    let cmd = interaction.commandName;

    if (bot.commands.has(cmd)) {
        command = bot.commands.get(cmd);
    } else {
        command = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
    }

    try {
        if (command) command.run(bot, interaction); 
    } catch (e) {
        logError(e, interaction.channel);
    }
});
```

Error handler module:

```js
const { errorLoggingWebhook, supportServer } = require("../config.json")
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = {
    "logError": (error, discordChannel) => {
        var errorID = createUUID();

        var params = {
            username: "Aspectfully Error Logging",
            content: `**${errorID}**:

            \`\`\`
            ${error}
            \`\`\``,
        }

        fetch(errorLoggingWebhook, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }) 

        return discordChannel.send(`An error occured while running that command. 
        
        If this continues to occur, please join our [support server](${supportServer}) and tell them an error is occuring.

        Also, give them the error ID \`${errorID}\`.`)
    }
}
```

This is an error that occurs. I know there is an easy solution to prevent it from occurring, but I just haven't implemented it yet. This way, I can test the error handling function.

(The error is because I am intentionally trying to process a page from Wikipedia that doesn't exist using the Wikipedia API as if it does exist, therefore trying to read values that don't exist)

```js
C:\Users\bekfe\OneDrive\Documents\Aspectfully\code\commands\wikipedia.js:36
                                wikiParseContents = wikiParse(Object.values(Object.values(JSON.parse(body))[0].text)[0], `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${encodeURI(suffix)}`);
                                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\bekfe\OneDrive\Documents\Aspectfully\code\commands\wikipedia.js:36:42
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I am not asking how to solve this specific error. I already know how to solve it. The problem is that the error handler doesn't catch it as an error - my question is about solving this specific error.

I have also tried doing the `await` function this way, but I have got the same result:

```js
const {bot} = require('../index');
const { logError } = require("../utils/ErrorHandling.js");

bot.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    let cmd = interaction.commandName;

    if (bot.commands.has(cmd)) {
        command = bot.commands.get(cmd);
    } else {
        command = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
    }

    if (command) {
        try {
            await command.run(bot, interaction); 
        } catch (e) {
            logError(e, interaction.channel);
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: is it a command handler?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? My bot has a command handler, yes, if that's what you're inquiring.

Comment: And do the errors come from within the command handler?

Comment: Usually, yes. I have already tried putting a try statement in the command handler, but that didn't work. It just acted like the try statement isn't there and threw an unhandled exception.

Comment: Can you edit that in?

Comment: Yes, I just did.

Comment: I mean can you edit the `try/catch` for the command handler

Comment: Oh, ok, yes. Hold on...

Edit: It has been added.

Comment: Please edit that in as a codeblock. Pictures of code are not good

Comment: Ah, ok. I will. Hold on. Edit: Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `command.run` is an async function, you need to `await` it to catch the error

```js
try {
    if (command) await command.run(bot, interaction); 
} catch (e) {
    logError(e, interaction.channel);
}
```

See how it works here:

```js
async function toThrow() {
 throw new Error("Test")
}
try {
  toThrow() //check your developer console as it doesn't show here
} catch (err) {
  console.log("An error occurred" + err)
}
```

```js
async function toThrow() {
  throw new Error("Test")
}
(async () => {
try {
  await toThrow()
 } catch (err) {
  console.log("An error occurred: " + err)
}
})()
```

Comment: I added your code, but it still is not working. An unhandled error crashes the bot and nothing relating to error logging ever fires.

Comment: *"it's still not working"* - what happens instead? Another error?

Comment: Edited it. Sorry - I just realized that is vauge.

Comment: what is the unhandled error?

Comment: I can't add new lines in comments. Should I edit it into the post?

Comment: If you have an unrelated error like that, you can ask a new question

Comment: I am not asking a question about that error. That isn't what I am trying to solve. I already know how to solve it. The problem is that the error handler doesn't catch it as an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240026/discussion-between-mrmythical-and-conny-wonny).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Nevermind this! The other person's answer turned out to start working for no apparent reason. It wasn't working earlier, but it has started working.

This solution is NOT a good option for anyone to do. As MrMythical and the Node.JS docs say, it can cause problems.

---

I ended up adding the unhandled exception listener inside of my `interactionCreate` like this upon the suggestion of an acquaintance on Discord:

```js
process.on("uncaughtException", (e) => {
    logError(e, interaction.channel)
});
```

I also realized I forgot to put the `createUUID` function back in the `ErrorHandling.js` file, so I added it back ([credit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)):

```js
createUUID = () => {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
       var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
       return v.toString(16);
    });
 }
```

This really isn't the best solution, but it's what I'm going with for now.

Comment: Not exiting the process on that event is a bad idea. You may have a corrupted node.js process

Comment: That is why I said that it is not an optimal solution. However, I am leaving it in for now, as nothing else seems to be working very well right now.